# why library functions should not be used in creating an os?

Tags: c, operating-system

I am planning to study about operating systems. I met with 2 doubts. Why we should not use library functions while creating an operating system?
What is the drawback in it?

Comment: Because there is no library.

Comment: The library will be binded with the final final executable file right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why we should not use library functions while creating an operating system? What is the drawback in it?

It depends on what you mean by "library functions".

You absolutely *should* try to use someone else's version of the functions from `<string.h>`, for example. If you're writing an OS, you've got plenty to do, why re-invent the wheel with something simple like `strcpy`?

You should use whatever open-source code you can *that has no dependencies*. I mean simple "leaf" functions like `strcpy` that have no dependencies.  If you look at the Linux kernel source code, you will certainly see standard library functions like `memcpy`, and `strlen`, etc. But you'll also see things like [`strncpy_from_user`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=strncpy_from_user) which are adapted to particular uses in the kernel (in this case copying a string from user-space to kernel-space).

What you *shouldn't* try to use (if it isn't obvious already) are things like `fopen`.  `fopen` is a wrapper around some code that makes a *system call* to the kernel to handle the actual opening of a file. Well clearly, if you **are** the kernel, you can't use this in your kernel.

Comment: And depending on the library implementation, it might be difficult to separate things like `fopen` from things like `strcpy` (did you know that `strtok` might rely on thread-local variables?), so the safest approach here is to not use anything.

Comment: @immibis To an extent, yes. Clearly if you're writing a kernel, you should pay attention to the code you're copying in - there's not *that* much in `<string.h>`. But in no case can I see `strcpy` being inseparable from `fopen`. Best (most common) case, it's just a C file you don't copy. Worst case, you don't copy/paste it into your project.